# How to match modifier visibility in render and viewport?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, visibility

How can I match the visibility of everything (specially modifiers) in viewport and render?

I do want to do this in a huge scene all at once.

Imagine that we have a big architectural scene that we want to render , every thing seems fine in viewport render but not in final render and we will waste a 48 hr of our rendering.

Because of a not visible displacement modifier in viewport but visible in render , so I want to be able to match these visibility options in both render and viewport not separated.

There should be an addon or an script or anything like that.

Comment: you could use driver for that

Answer (score 2):

For the modifiers, Make sure the Levels Viewport and Render have the same value. Also, don't forget to turn on Realtime Display which is circled in red.

[image]

If you mean visibility (hidden), then make sure the "Disable in Viewports" and "Disable in Render" are highlighted/Turned On.

Turned On = Highlighted

Turned Off = Grayed Out

[image]

Comment: YES! the first one was where i meant to do , but i have a huge big scene and i don't have time to match all of them by hand , so i want to be able to do all at once , thanks for your effort mate , i'll like your answer but if you can find any way to do it all at once i'll accept the answer

Comment: if you want to do all at once you would need a python script. But honestly, why do you want to do that? it makes no sense - especially in a big scene. You might not be able to move in your viewport again due to lack of memory/computer power.

Comment: A big scene with 200 objects , i can't check it out to find which object is wrong that i accidentally hit the render visibility and corrupted a 48 hr render because of that , this is why i want to do it all at once .

Comment: @user256371 the easiest way would be using a python script (i don't know any for this circumstance since it usually crashes blender when you try to achieve what you want). 

However, if you have the time, you can create an object driver with custom properties. With this object driver and custom properties, you can manually connect them and you won't have to worry about changing values for all your object in the future. This will take a lot of time I believe.

Another solution is to use Eevee as your render. Eeeve offers real-time render and is much quicker than cycles.

Comment: you can achieve the same result as cycles but you will need to do a lot of tweaking.